# Type changes column into table

Tags: azure-databricks

I am applying change data field and using below formula

```sql
max_version = spark.sql("DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename>").collect()[0][0]
delta_df = spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM table_changes('<tablename>',{max_version}) order by _commit_timestamp")
display(delta_df)
```

I have one  requirement. I need to include the column `"_commit_timestamp"` into `<tablename>` how the new column can be created in existing table

Comment: Could you share with sample data ,your attempt and explain it better?

Comment: delta_df = spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM table_changes('<tablename>',{max_version}) order by _commit_timestamp")
display(delta_df)   I need to add the new column called _commit_timestamp into <tablename> how it can be done

Comment: Do you want to create new column in delta table? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes Bhavani you are write

Answer (score 0):

I am having delta table in my environment with below columns

[image]

I used below code to add new column to the table

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit


from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

spark.read.format("delta").load('dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/empp')\
  .withColumn("_commit_timestamp", lit(''))\
  .write\
  .format("delta")\
  .mode("overwrite")\
  .option("overwriteSchema", "true")\
  .save('dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/empp')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I need to access _commit_timestampe  column from the above mentioned delta_df  and add particular column to <tablename>

Comment: Try below code once

delta_df.select(col("_commit_timestamp"))
new_df = delta_df.withColumn("<column_name>", lit("<default_value>"))
new_df.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("<tablename>")